# Promise/async-await with mongoose, returning empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, async-await

The console in the end returns empty array. 
The console runs before ids.map function finishes

```
var ids = [];
var allLync = []
var user = await User.findOne(args.user)
ids.push(user._id)
user.following.map(x => {
    ids.push(x)
})
ids.map(async x => {
    var lync = await Lync.find({ "author": x })
    lync.map(u => {
        allLync.push[u]
    })
})

console.log(allLync)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the value of `lync` - try adding `console.log(lync)` to see what  `Lync.find({ "author": x })` is returning to you - by the way, that is a really bad use of `.map` - the way you wrote that, you may as well use `.forEach`

Comment: @JaromandaX you're right but a small nit: OP actually does need `.map` here since they need the promises back to await them before the `log`

Comment: except the values returned my `.map` are not being actually used - I said the way he uses .map he may as well use .forEach .... but .map is the right method if it is used correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.map` code isn't awaited, so the `console.log` happens before the mapping happens.

If you want to wait for a map - you can use `Promise.all` with `await`:

```
var ids = [];
var allLync = []
var user = await User.findOne(args.user)
ids.push(user._id)
user.following.map(x => {
    ids.push(x)
})
// note the await
await Promise.all(ids.map(async x => {
    var lync = await Lync.find({ "author": x })
    lync.map(u => {
        allLync.push(u); // you had a typo there
    })
}));

console.log(allLync)
```

Note though since you're using `.map` you can shorten the code significantly:

```
const user = await User.findOne(args.user)
const ids = users.following.concat(user._id);
const allLync = await Promise.all(ids.map(id => Lync.find({"author": x })));
console.log(allLync);
```

Comment: It worked, I learnt a new concept cause of you. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Promise.map() is now an option that would be a tiny bit more succinct option, if you don't mind using bluebird. 
It could look something like:

```
const user = await User.findOne(args.user);
const ids = users.following.concat(user._id);
const allLync = await Promise.map(ids, (id => Lync.find({"author": x })));
console.log(allLync);
```

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html. I have really enjoyed using it.